# Trying to groupby and summarise in python

Tags: python, group-by

Basically I want the bins to be in a column of themselves please see code and output. Python

```
    graph_data = housing_data.groupby(['Date','Bins']).Price.mean()

    graph_data
```

```
Date     Bins    
2016-01  (5, 10]              NaN
         (10, 15]    1.009000e+06
2016-03  (0, 5]      1.244532e+06
         (5, 10]     1.221559e+06
         (10, 15]    1.098541e+06
2016-04  (0, 5]      1.085015e+06
         (5, 10]     1.086503e+06
         (10, 15]    9.220241e+05
2016-05  (0, 5]      1.019418e+06
         (5, 10]     1.139064e+06
         (10, 15]    9.416809e+05
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking to reshape your data into what's called wide-form data.  What you have currently is long-form data.  To switch back and forth between the two in `pandas` use `melt` and `pivot` (or `stack` and `unstack`).  ([Check out this post](https://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/) or [my more general post](https://stmorse.github.io/journal/tidyverse-style-pandas.html).)

I don't have your data, but try

```py
(housing_data.groupby(['Date', 'Bins'])
             .agg({'Price': 'mean'})
             .reset_index()
             .pivot(index='Date', columns='Bins', 
                    values='Price'))
```

(The `reset_index` line is an unfortunate necessity to force pandas to recognize Date as a column again after the `agg` command.)

If you want to rename the bins, you could use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) before the `groupby` call, but it would be easier if you just create your own bins with `pd.cut`.  Here's an example using `iris`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
iris['bins'] = pd.cut(iris['sepal_length'], 
                      bins=3, 
                      labels=['lo', 'med', 'hi'])
(iris.groupby(['species', 'bins'])
     .agg({'sepal_length': 'mean'})
     .reset_index()
     .pivot(index='species', columns='bins', 
            values='sepal_length'))
```

```
bins        lo          med         hi
species         
setosa      4.959574    5.733333    NaN
versicolor  5.281818    6.055556    6.900000
virginica   4.900000    6.265625    7.294118
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to have the bins title removed and the values be the headers of the columns or is this the format of a pivot table?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to rename the bins and/or column names, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking.  Suggest you edit your post with what you *want* your table to look like.